# Evaluate user-defined variables in FROM and WHERE clauses (Oracle DEFINE command)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use the `DEFINE` command in Oracle to define strings and evaluate them in the `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses of a query.

I want to select all the credits that started in January 2018 from the tables `credits_201801`, `credits_201802`, `credits_201803`, `credits_201804`, `credits_201805` and `credits_201806`. In other words, I want to visualize the behavior of the January 2018 credits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 months after they started.

For example, I tried the following code to check the status of the `Jan 2018` credits in `Feb 2018`:

```sql
DEFINE crop   = '2018-01-01';
DEFINE crop_n = ADD_MONTHS(&crop, 1); -- I want this to return 2018-01-01 plus `n = 1` months
DEFINE table_ = REPLACE(SUSBTR(&crop_n, 1, 7), '-'); -- I want this to return '201802'

SELECT
    PERSON_ID,
    BANK_ID,
    ACCOUNT_ID,
    START_DATE,
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(&crop_n, &crop) AS PERIOD,
    DAYS_OVERDUE
FROM
    'MDB.CREDITS_' || &table_ -- I want this to be evaluated as 'MDB.CREDITS_201802'
WHERE
    START_DATE >= &crop -- Credits that started on or after Jan 1 2018
    AND START_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(&crop, 1) -- Credits that started before Feb 1 2018
```

The user-defined variables are working well in the `SELECT` clause, but it seems that the `FROM` section is evaluating the table as a literal string rather than the name of the table. The `WHERE` clause is not working either.

I specifically need used `DEFINE` because it's the only command I know of that doesn't require me to use `INSERT INTO` (I am only allowed to select).

Comment: Hint:  `execute immediate`.  You need dynamic SQL if you want to change identifiers in a query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `&` signifies a substitution variable which (in user interfaces such as SQL/Plus that support them) will be replaced with their value before the code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is written like `date '2018-01-01'`, not `'2018-01-01'`.

`define` expects a single value, so if you want it to include blank spaces then you'll need to quote it.

To construct a string in `YYYYMM` format from a date, you need to use `to_char(dateval,'YYYYMM')`.

You also need to evaluate the `table_` expression so you can substitute a literal string into the table name in the final query.

```
define crop   = "date '2018-01-01'"
define crop_n = "add_months(&crop, 1)" -- I want this to return 2018-01-01 plus `n = 1` months

column table_ new_value table_

select to_char(&crop_n,'YYYYMM') as table_ from dual;

prompt crop   = &crop
prompt crop_n = &crop_n
prompt table_ = &table_

select person_id
     , bank_id
     , account_id
     , start_date
     , months_between(&crop_n, &crop) as period
     , days_overdue
from   MDB.CREDITS_&table_ -- I want this to be evaluated as 'MDB.CREDITS_201802'
where  start_date >= &crop -- Credits that started on or after Jan 1 2018
and    dcredfaperturacta < add_months(&crop, 1) -- Credits that started before Feb 1 2018
/
```

The `column x new_value y` setting captures the last value of column `x` into substitution variable `y`. It’s originally meant for page headers in reports, but very handy for scripting. You can hide the output using `set termout off`. (`set termout on` to restore terminal output.)

This will generate and run

```
crop   = date '2018-01-01'
crop_n = add_months(date '2018-01-01', 1)
table_ = 201802

select person_id
     , bank_id
     , account_id
     , start_date
     , months_between(add_months(date '2018-01-01', 1), date '2018-01-01') as period
     , days_overdue
from   MDB.CREDITS_201802 -- I want this to be evaluated as 'MDB.CREDITS_201802'
where  start_date >= date '2018-01-01' -- Credits that started on or after Jan 1 2018
and    dcredfaperturacta < add_months(date '2018-01-01', 1) -- Credits that started before Feb 1 2018
```

Note following comments: this is Oracle SQL*Plus syntax. Other tools such as Toad, PL/SQL Developer and SQL Developer support it to some extent and using different methods. Not all SQL*Plus syntax is guaranteed to work in all other tools. In PL/SQL Developer it only works in a Command Window. In SQL Developer you will need to use "Run as Script" (F5) and not the regular "Run" (Ctrl-Enter).

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a problem though. The `FROM` clause is returning `"SQL command not properly ended"`. Also, could you explain why you added quotation marks around `add_months(&crop, 1)`? If I had `add_months(&crop,1)` would they still be necessary? Finally, what do the `column` and `promt` sections do in this code?

Comment: Yes, the quotes were for the space. `prompt` just prints a message - I used it to confirm the values. `column ... new_value ...` captures values from query results into a substitution variable. It’s originally meant for page headers in reports, but very handy for scripting.

Comment: To diagnose what is wrong with the `from` clause, can you run it with `set verify on`? Also what was the value of `&table_`?

Comment: When I run everything up to `promt table_ = &table` a window pops up telling me to `Enter value for table_`. So I think the `table_` variable is not storing `201802`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `define table_ = to_char(&crop_n, 'yyyymm')` somewhere?

Comment: No, the `column ... new_value` construction populates the variable. This works in SQL\*Plus, but from your comment it sounds like you are using something else. In SQL Developer for example, you would have to use "Run as Script" (F5) not the regular "Run" (Ctrl-Enter).  In PL/SQL Developer you would have to run it in a Command Window, etc.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that running something on SQL Developer as a script and running a statement implied different outcomes. It worked perfectly when using `F5`. It's working now. Thanks!